# how do I set the width of p-tree to fill the available space?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I cannot properly set the width to fill the available space for a `p-tree` primeng control.
It works in chrome devtools when I do it manually but doesn't when I do it in the style file of my component.

Stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-gjz1po

The tree will stay 18em of width no matter what.
Thank you in advance.

The html code:

```
<p-tree [value]=filesTree1></p-tree>
```

The css code:

```
.ui-tree {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use styleClass property of p-tree control.

```
<p-tree [value]=filesTree1 [styleClass]="'my-tree'"></p-tree>
```

Add below css in tree.scss file.

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-tree.my-tree {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-mc88uu)

Comment: yeah, :host ::ng-deep .ui-tree is the right class in scss. You're the man!